# signInWithRedirect is available in React Native app

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am still new to React Native and I would like to let users use a google account on my React Native app. My question is if signInWithRedirect function is available in native apps. I first wrote signInWithPopup, but I got an error and found out I couldn't use it in native apps. Also, I used a redirect function, but it didn't work well.

I deleted all my code and used createUserWithEmailAndPassword, but honestly, I still want users to log in with their google accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not possible in React Native world. It seems that you already have some web experience, so this deep dive might be helpful for you to understand why React Native allows you to use web technologies while developing a native app: https://www.infoq.com/articles/react-native-introduction/

**But the solution you are looking for is [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/)** which is the officially recommended collection of packages that brings React Native support for all Firebase services on both Android and iOS apps.

1. Be sure to follow `Firebase Authentication` setup instructions: https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage
2. Setup `Firebase Authentication` with `google-signin`: https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin

Comment: Oh, this is where it comes in. I knew it but it seemed like it'd be too complicated for me to connect with my react native app. My question is because my app is made in react native, which instructions of ios or android should I follow? ios because I use Mac??

Answer (score 0):

Shorten yourself and use  [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/)
And that using tool [Authentication](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage)
But make sure that the application is well connected, then you will get many features that save you time, such as: Dashboard, mail confirmation, and types of login methods (Facebook and ...) Even that you can create a login method as a guest

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).